# Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to create an SIR Model (solving 3 differential equations with two parameters) and plot the solution for this on MATLAB and I keep getting the error 'Not enough input arguments'. I really can't see where I am going wrong. Here is the code:

```
function dx = sir(t,x) 
dx=[0; 0; 0]; 
beta = .003;
delta = 1;
dx(1)= -beta *x(1)*x(2); 
dx(2)=beta*x(1)*x(2)-delta*x(2); 
dx(3)=delta*x(2); 
%options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'NonNegative', [1 2 3]); 
[t,x] = ode45('sir', [0 10], [1000 1 0], options); 
plot(t,x); 
%legend('S', 'I', 'R'); 
end
```

Comment: First, why don't you just copy the code in the Question? Second, can you show how you call the function `sir(t,x);`?

Comment: The code in the question:

Comment: function dx = sir(t,x)
dx=[0; 0; 0];
beta = .003;
delta = 1;
dx(1)= -beta *x(1)*x(2);
dx(2)=beta*x(1)*x(2)-delta*x(2);
dx(3)=delta*x(2);


%options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'NonNegative', [1 2 3]);
[t,x] = ode45('sir', [0 10], [1000 1 0], options);
plot(t,x);
%legend('S', 'I', 'R');

Comment: i've been told that I have to call outside the function in order for my solution to be plot - how do i do this? thanks

Comment: first of all you need to close your function by using end and then call it from workspace

Comment: Also note the line ode45('sir', [0 10], [1000 1 0], options);  will recall you function infinity times because of the name used which is sir, you need to rename it.

Comment: @Anonaanon: Please update your question and put the code there.

Comment: @Alyafey I did exactly that and then I got the error 'Undefined function or variable 't''.

Comment: Ok,a question what's the need of parameter t since you didn't use it?

Comment: @Alyafey Because the differential equations are with respect to dt i.e. dx/dt (with respect to time)

Comment: I know but I don't see it anywhere  in your code also there is a notification from matlab telling you that you didn't use.

Comment: @Alyafey so should i take it out?

Comment: if you only passing x you should take it out

Comment: Yes, you should paste your code above! This helps us to test your code!

Comment: I've just edited with the code

Comment: Ive tried pasting the code onto the question but it appears in paragraphs as opposed to a list :S

Comment: @karl71 ive entered the code that you put in however when i run it i keep getting the error 'Multiple left-hand sides must be separated by commas'. this is line 9 column 2

Comment: @Anonaanon. Yes. remove the "%" before "options..." And, how do you call the function? X is a vector? Give me an example please so I can solve your question

Comment: @karl71 im not too sure of how to call the function.. x isn't a vector its a variable. My professor told me to call the function outside of the function but I'm so confused as to how to do this and have been spending hours on this

Comment: @Anonaanon. I've got this error: "Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached." Maybe you should try to modify the parameters you pass to "ode45" I think you're trying to make a calculation with a huge amount of points so this is the reason why matlab stops. It seems to me that the input parameter X is the function you what to compute the differential calculus. Maybe you should try to ask your professor for some help. I don't know how to solve this. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a serious misconception about how function calls and recursion work, or possibly you're just not familiar with programming. You need two separate things:

1. Define a function and save it as `sir.m`. This defines your ODE. It should contain:
   `function dx = sir(t,x)
   beta = .003;
   delta = 1;
   dx(1)= -beta *x(1)*x(2); 
   dx(2)=beta*x(1)*x(2)-delta*x(2); 
   dx(3)=delta*x(2);`
2. Run the code to solve your ODE. This can be directly pasted into the command window as long as `sir.m` is in your path or current directory:
   `options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-4, 'NonNegative', [1 2 3]); 
   [t,x] = ode45('sir', [0 10], [1000 1 0], options); 
   plot(t,x); 
   legend('S', 'I', 'R');`

Note that step 1 *defines* the `sir` function and step 2 *uses* it. This needs to happen in two separate steps to prevent `sir` from calling itself (or more precisely in your case, calling a function, `ode45`, which calls `sir` again). This is called recursion and is not what you should be doing here.